# Serverless: Layers No file matches include / exclude patterns

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

My serverless.yml file works fine as soon as I add layers I starting getting this error

> Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
>
> ```
> No file matches include / exclude patterns
> ```

```
service: foundation

useDotenv: true

custom:
  name: foundation

provider:
  name: aws
  stackName: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}
  region: us-east-1
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  environment:
    REGION: ${self:provider.region}
    STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}

layers:
  certificates:
    path: certificate 

plugins:
  - serverless-deployment-bucket
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
  - serverless-plugin-typescript

functions:
  - ${file(./src/handler/function.yml)}

resources:
  - ${file(./resources/outputs.yml)}
```

**runtime: Node.js**

**Note: using layers to add certificates to lambda**

**Serverless version: 2.31.0**

Answer (score 2):

You may be getting this error if you execlude the directory where the layer is running through the plugins you use or in another part of the yml file. Maybe editing it this way will solve the problem

[this link](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/5892#issuecomment-516035714) has an explanation about it

```
layers:
  certificates:
    package:
      include:
        - ./your/layer/path/**
```

Comment: I tried this one, anyways I fixed the problem
it was typescript build issue

Comment: @NomanMaqsood  Could you describe the Typescript build issue you fixed?